# Google Chrome does not refresh Flex Application

Tags: apache-flex, caching, flash

I have an online flex app that is served via an html page.

Its critical that the flex app is refreshed in the user's cache every time that it changes. To help ensure that this happens, I change the name of the swf file every time that it changes. In addition, the html page contains the following lines of code:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
```

Using these techniques, FF and IE always seem to grab the latest swf file every time. Google chrome, however, NEVER gets the latest swf file - the only way to get the update is to hit shift+refresh in chrome.

Is there a fail-safe way for me to ensure that the latest swf file is always delivered to the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have much experience with chrome, but you might find this thread helpful:

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=1d04b43217799be3&hl=en

It seems that chrome does not recognize "no-cache" and instead recognizes cache-control: no-store